# Generate multiple PDFs and zip them for download, all in a single view

Tags: django, python-3.x, zip, xhtml2pdf

I am using `xhtml2pdf` to generate PDFs in my Django View. The idea is to loop over all the instances that are there in the query, then for each instance create a PDF, then add all the generated PDFs to one zip File for download. The `xtml2pdf` logic is working okay but the looping logic is what gives me headache.

So this is my function so far:

```
def bulk_cover_letter(request, ward_id, school_cat_id, cheque_number):
    school_type = SchoolType.objects.get(id=school_cat_id)

    schools_in_school_type = Applicant.objects.filter(
        school_type=school_type, ward_id=ward_id, award_status='awarded'
    ).order_by().values_list('school_name', flat=True).distinct()

    for school in schools_in_school_type:
        beneficiaries = Applicant.objects.filter(school_type=school_type, ward_id=ward_id, award_status='awarded', school_name=school)
        total_amount_to_beneficiaries = Applicant.objects.filter(school_type=school_type, ward_id=ward_id, award_status='awarded', school_name=school).aggregate(total=Sum('school_type__amount_allocated'))
        context = {
            'school_name' : school,
            'beneficiaries' : beneficiaries,
            'total_amount_to_beneficiaries' : total_amount_to_beneficiaries,
            'title' : school + ' Disbursement Details',
            'cheque_number': cheque_number
        }

        response = HttpResponse('<title>Cover Letter</title>', content_type='application/pdf')
        filename = "%s.pdf" %(cheque_number)
        content = "inline; filename=%s" %(filename)
        response['Content-Disposition'] = content
        template = get_template('cover_letter.html')
        html = template.render(context)
        result = io.BytesIO()
        pdf = pisa.CreatePDF(
            html, dest=response, link_callback=link_callback)
        if not pdf.error:
            # At this point I can generate a single PDF.
            # But no idea on what to do next.

    # The zipping logic should follow here after looping all the instances - (schools)
```

From that Point I have no idea on what to do next. Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

Utils.py

```
def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html  = template.render(context_dict)
    buffer = BytesIO()
    p = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), buffer)
    pdf = buffer.getvalue()
    buffer.close()
    if not p.err:
        return pdf#HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None


def generate_zip(files):
    mem_zip = BytesIO()

    with zipfile.ZipFile(mem_zip, mode="w",compression=zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
        for f in files:
            zf.writestr(f[0], f[1])

    return mem_zip.getvalue()
```

Views.py

```
def generate_attendance_pdf(modeladmin, request, queryset):

    template_path = 'student/pdf_template.html'

    files = []

    for q in queryset:
        context = {
            'firstname': q.firstname,
            'lastname': q.lastname,
            'p_firstname': q.bceID.firstname
        }
        pdf = render_to_pdf(template_path, context)
        files.append((q.firstname + ".pdf", pdf))

    full_zip_in_memory = generate_zip(files)

    response = HttpResponse(full_zip_in_memory, content_type='application/force-download')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format('attendnace.zip')

    return response
```

Obviously, you have to modify the context/names to what you need.

Credit to -> Neil Grogan https://www.neilgrogan.com/py-bin-zip/

Answer (score 0):

If you need to generate several PDF files and send them as a response in a zip file then you can store the reports in memory and set it as `dest` when you call `pisa.CreatePDF`. Then have a list of reports in memory, [zip](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/zipfile.html) them, and send as a Django response specifying another content type.

For example:

```
reports = tempfile.TemporaryDirectory()
report_files = {}
for school in schools_in_school_type:
    # ... same code that renerates `html`
    mem_fp = BytesIO()
    pisa.CreatePDF(html, dest=mem_fp)
    report_files[filename] = mem_fp
mem_zip = BytesIO()
with zipfile.ZipFile(mem_zip, mode="w") as zf:
    for filename, content in report_files.items():
            zf.write(filename, content)
response = HttpResponse(mem_zip, content_type='application/force-download')
response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format('cover_letters.zip')
```

This still generates an error of `[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'cheque_number.pdf'`.

Comment: You should be able to create a `zipfile.ZipFile` from a `BytesIO` object that you can write the PDFs to directly I think without the need for a tempfile

Comment: @IainShelvington could you please share your function?

Comment: @Yann, could you be more elaborate on this part? `you can create temporary files using tempfile and set it as dest when you call pisa.CreatePDF. Then have a list of these temp file paths` . Probably use some code?

Comment: @Yann I'm getting this error: `stat: path should be string, bytes, os.PathLike or integer, not _io.BytesIO`

Comment: I edited the `zf.write(content, filename)` to `zf.write(filename, content)` but now I get the error - `File not found, <cheque_number>.pdf`. Any insights?

Comment: Did anyone get the answer to this?